# How do I convert Data.ByteString.Char8 to Data.ByteString.Lazy for use in Data.Binary.Get?

Tags: haskell

I am in the midst of converting a package from using **GHC.IO.Handle** for networking to **Network.Connection.Connection**.  One of the pain points is the number of places where **Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString** is being changed to **Data.ByteString.Char8.ByteString**.

An example function is:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

-- gets the size of the frame
-- the bytestring should be at least 7 bytes long, otherwise this method will fail
peekFrameSize :: BL.ByteString -> PayloadSize
peekFrameSize = runGet f
  where
    f = do
      void $ getWord8 -- 1 byte
      void $ (get :: Get ChannelID) -- 2 bytes
      get :: Get PayloadSize -- 4 bytes
```

How do I convert **Data.ByteString.Char8.ByteString** to **Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString** for use in **Data.Binary.Get**?

Comment: Are you looking for [Data.ByteString.Lazy.fromStrict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:fromStrict)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `Data.ByteString.Char8` is a module, not a type.  Same with `Data.ByteString.Lazy`.  That said, and assuming the obvious, then notice that `Data.ByteString.Char8.ByteString` is actually a re-export of `Data.ByteString.ByteString`.  So all you need is the `fromStrict` function mentioned by Mikail Glushenkov.

Comment: Well, that was obvious. Thank you Mikhail and Thomas.

Comment: Better late than never.  I corrected the module/type confusion in my question.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea Great, glad to see you're still hacking away!